# When I res.render after fetching parameters from URL, the page loads with the prior URL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

**Task:**to retrieve product based on product_id:
Example: When I hit localhost:8080/products/44566
the server responds with product page for product with product id : 44566

The Home page where there are products and when I click on them,they pass the product_id to the Angular JS controller like this:

```
$scope.getProductPage = function(product_id){

        // window.location.assign("/products/"+product_id);

        $http({
            url:"/products/"+product_id,
            method : "GET"
        }).then(function mySuccess(response){

            window.location.assign("/products/"+product_id);

        }, function myError(response){

        });

    };
```

This sends data to the Node server here:

```
//API to GET the sell page
router.get('/products/:product_id', function(req, res, next) {

  var product_id = req.params.product_id;
  console.log('product_id', product_id);

  res.render("productPage", {data: req.params.product_id});

});
```

This means I render productPage.ejs and the response goes back successfully to my angular js controller:

$scope.getProductPage = function(product_id){

```
        // window.location.assign("/products/"+product_id);

        $http({
            url:"/products/"+product_id,
            method : "GET"
        }).then(function mySuccess(response){

            window.location.assign("/products/"+product_id);

        }, function myError(response){

        });

    };
```

wheree it uses window.location.assign("/products/"+product_id); to go to the page with that specific product_id. But when that page loads, I see the following behavior of the server:
[image]

**Notice that all the URLs go with request /products/ where as onlt the main route URL should be passed like that**

Answer (score 0):

By "this behaviour" I am assuming that you mean the stylesheets/images not being loaded properly.

This is because in your HTML page (or rather the `.ejs` template file), you are putting a document relative URLs for loading them. For eg.:

```
<img src="images/xyz.png" />
```

whereas, these should be made absolute URIs:

```
<img src="/images/xyz.png" />
```

Alternatively, you can use the `<base>` tag in your `<head>` node:

```
<base href="/">
```